# iOS Universal Link: Django Python Support

Tags: ios, python-3.x, django, heroku, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to integrate the universal link in my iOS app. In order to test, I  configured a sample Django application on Heroku and added the apple-app-site association file to the root of the application.

GET request to ***domain_url/apple-app-site-association*** provides the following result

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
           {
             "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.com.app.myapp",
             "paths": ["*"]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Following is the code in python that serves the request

```
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'apple-app-site-association')
with open(path , 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
response = HttpResponse(content=data)
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
return response
```

I tried the branch.io validator with my server URL and it was fine.

But https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/ is returning the following response

> Error no apps with domain entitlements The entitlement data used to
> verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released
> version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.

I configured the associated domain and updated the profiles. I tried opening the app on iPhone by clicking the link in both the mail app and notes app. But the link is opening to Safari, not the app.

I tried reinstalling the app. But nothing works. Where did I go wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

An easier way is to just render a template as `JSON` at a URL.  Below is an example:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

path('.well-known/apple-app-site-association', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='frontend/apple-app-site-association', content_type='application/json',)),
```

Then you can just put the file in your templates folder.